# Pooled analysis of different but very similar measures; what is the best practice?

Tags: multiple-regression, meta-analysis, z-score, pooling

I have three small data sets which include scores on global cognitive assessments. Two data sets use the score on the Mini Mental State Exam, one uses the score of the Montreal Cognitive Assessment. here are some points of note about these scores:

- Both are brief screeners of cognition which test a few different domains of cognition.
- Both are scored out of 30 possible points, with higher scores indicating greater cognitive function.
- [Prior research has been done](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4562190/) and proposes a "score translation" from MoCA to MMSE.

I would like to do pooled analysis with these data sets, but I am unsure how best to handle the cognitive variables given the difference. Here are options I know I have, but I'm not sure if one option is a winner above others/what the pros and cons of each are, and was hoping y'all could give me some guidance or reading on them. Options:

1. Calculate Z-score of the cognitive variable for each data set.
2. Calculate a Z-score of the cognitive variable for the pooled data.
3. "Translate" the MoCA to MMSE score as described in the link above, analyze absolute MMSE/translated MMSE scores.

Most researchers tend to prefer z-scores in meta analysis, but as I have the actual underlying data rather than just reported effect sizes, I am wondering if there is a best way to approach this cognitive variable from a statistical validity and robustness standpoint?  I considered dichotomizing cognition to impaired vs. not and using each test's cut off score, but I know that loses a lot of precision so already threw that option out. (Oh, these values will be the outcomes of interest, or later a covariate, in multiple regression models.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have raw data, you can convert the scales/instruments and perform an individual patient data (IPD) meta-analysis.

If you do not have IPD:

**Approach 1:**

1. Establish a hierarchy of scales/instruments.  When a study reports two or more scales, you should extract and include in the analysis only the scale highest in the hierarchy.
2. Since the scales/instruments are on the same metric (e.g., 0to 30) you meta-analyze them directly. No need for transformation.

The underlying premise is that both scales/instruments capture/assess cognitive functions in a comparable manner and are highly correlated/interchangeable.

**Approach 2:**

1. Perform a bivariate meta-analysis, modelling both outcomes simultaneously.
   Check this paper: https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0962280211432219